# creating NSURL crashes on IOS5 only

Tags: ios5, exc-bad-access

Upgraded device to iOS 5, now the app crashes. Nuts... 
It's a camera application. Records video. I have a `playMovie` procedure to play the captured video. That function needs to create a `NSURL` using the path (`NSString`) that points to the video file. But the `NSURL` creation crashes with `exc_bad_access`.  2 nights trying to solve this, no luck. Beginning to suspect the problem is older version of xcode 3.2.5.
Here's the snippet...

```
    - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
    /// after I verify that file type is movie ....
    videoFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    NSURL    *url    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath];
    ... at this point the app crashes.
```

ALREADY TRIED:
- Moving `NSURL` creation from playMovie proc to within `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` (as shown above). Still crashes.
- Adding `isDirectory:NO`].  still crashes.
- printing the path string in log... path looks just fine (it's not empty or overwritten)
- comment out the `NSURL` and just save the MOV file without playing it. works fine. But I need the URL in order to play the movie.

device log:

Exception Type:  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`

Exception Codes: `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x10000010`

console msg:

Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Can't find dlopen function, so it is not possible to load shared libraries.)

--- adding more details (8/30/12) ---

`videoFilePath` is an `NSString` declared in my `viewController.h`.  It has `@property (retain,nonatomic)`, and it's synthesized. It is NOT alloc'ed anywhere, so it is used as a constant. The snipped of code above shows how the media url is assigned to `videoFilePath` (as a constant, not alloc'ed).
After this I open a `UIActionSheet` for user to "Play Movie", or "Save Movie", or "Cancel" (someday will add Youtube option).  In the actionsheet, if user picks `PlayMovie` I call (void)playMovie procedure.  In that procedure, I declare the *url object initiating it with the path stored in `videoFilePath`.  Worked like a charm until upgraded to IOS 5.
I just tried to preallocate the `NSString` `videoFilePath` inside `(void)viewDidLoad`, so that it's used allocated instead of constant. But that didn't solve it.
I just tried upgrading XCODE to 4.2. I don't get the msg "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable" anymore. But still crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Thanks! Thanks!  Thanks!

Comment: can you show us how are you saving the videoFilePath and it's value  when the crash occurs

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are extracting a path from an NSURL object, then creating an new NSURL object from that path. fileURLWithPath: is not happy with that path for some reason. It could be that the path does not conform to RFC 1808, and therefore the previous path call results in videoFilePath == nil.

But why do this conversion? Just use:

```
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

Comment: Man, I think you killed it.  Just unable to test now because I upgraded xcode to 4.2 and it won't run the app on ios 5.  So I'm downgrade xcode again to test this (funny, older xcode works on IOS 5). But it's looking like your solution will work (builds and runs on older IOS just fine). I'll be able to confirm tomorrow. Many thanks.

Comment: Just adding a comment in case someone else runs into this... I still have no fix but the issue is not the code. It's related to compiler, SDK, etc. After many re-installs, I still get it. App freezes. Console saying:  "No copy of libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session."  Still trying all sorts of stuff. My only advice at this time is DO NOT UPGRADE DEVICE TO 5.1.1 IF YOU'RE ON SNOW LEOPARD!!!

Comment: Solved... Forgot to retain the URL object. So in the playMovie procedure, when it tried to get the movie at that path, the URL was already gone.   Once I added the [url retain], the app worked.